# Why I can not give a discord user a role? c#

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I want to give a Discord client a role in a ReactionAdded event. Why does not this work?

```
public static async Task AddedReactEvent(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> message, ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketReaction reaction)
{
    if (channel.Id == 504031332612046881)
    {
        if (reaction.Emote.Name == "PS4")
        {
            var context = new CommandContext(_client, message.Value);
            var role = context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PS4");

        Console.WriteLine(role.Color.ToString());
            await (reaction.User.Value as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? What happens? Do you get an exception?

Comment: No it does nothing! In the console is nothing. But i print a line to the Console!

Comment: Ohh sorry!
"System.NullReferenceException" in Discord.Net.Commands.dll
This is in my debug view!

Comment: But the code works fine when i write a message under if(reaction.Emote.Name == "PS4")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly seems to be a `NullReferenceException`. This could be because your `var role` could be null. You can find it out if you use breakpoints and run the debugger.

Also your method of getting the `role` though the `channel` through the `_client` seems inappropriate. Why bother to create a new `commandContext` just get the role from `Cacheable channel`.

```
var role = ((ITextChannel) channel).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PS4");
```

This ought to get you the role. Also **if** it is your private server you are coding for dont bother to use the role name thing. Instead use the role id something like

```
var role = ((ITextChannel) channel).Guild.GetRole(437634977941684226);
```

You can get the role id by mentioning the role and placing a `\` before it (escaping it).

Like

> \@bot

becomes

> <@&437634977941684226>

and 437634977941684226 is your roleID